# pytesseract unable to detect simple BW image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

So I have been trying to get some text from an image using OCR. The image is fairly simple with white background and black letters. But pytesseract is unable to detect it. Attaching a sample image for reference

[image]

Now initially the image resolution is fairly small. I am resizing and sharpening up the image but still while running this code

```
img_x = Image.fromarray(bw_image)
w, h = bw_image.shape
img_y = img_x.resize((h*10, w*10))
pytesseract.image_to_string(img_y.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN))
```

The output is **'\x0c'**

Comment: I've removed the OpenCV tag. this isn't using opencv nor is the issue one of using or not using OpenCV. it's an OCR problem, or rather a tesseract problem, because tesseract is being difficult as always.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I could solve this issue by keeping the original image(don't resize) and then using --psm 7 as config for tesseract

```
img_x = Image.fromarray(bw_image)
pytesseract.image_to_string(img_x, config=r'--psm 7')
```

Using this tesseract is able to detect the correct alphabets most of the time

Comment: Your answer would be improved by explaining the significance of `--psm 7`.